# Selecting Verts I dont want

Tags: modeling

When selecting vertext points with the drag and select option, Blender will select Verts outside of the area I am trying to cover. I've been looking through multiple forums and they all say the same thing( To adjust these settings or turn off Minimaps) Nothing is working so far and this just started happening out of nowhere. Updated to current .79 version today and have the Nvidia drivers updated. Any other suggestions?

The Red circle shows what I want to select, the red X is the parts it is selecting that I don't want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the box-select tool [b] in edit mode adds to the selection. That unwanted point was part of your previous selection. You can remove this by simply holding down [shift] and right clicking the unwanted vertex.

Whenever you want to make a new selection using the box-select, remember to first de-select everything by pressing the [a] key. The box-select tool shouldn't make any selections outside of its influence area.